# MYSQL Query Age Calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my MySQL Query to return the age from the date of birth

```sql
SELECT
    PensionerDOB,
    YEAR( CURDATE() ) AS Year, 
    DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( PensionerDOB, '%d-%M-%Y' ), '%Y') AS age,
    
    YEAR( CURDATE() ) - DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(`PensionerDOB`, '%d-%M-%Y' ), '%Y' ) AS differenage 

FROM
    `pensionerbasicdata`
```

The query is executed. But it returns the age difference is in a negative value.

[image: Output]

Comment: Why are you using `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT` _together_? You don't need to do that.

Comment: If someone is born in 1945, they are not 2045 years old... Please use more accurate column names.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but can't you reverse the minuend and subtrahend to reverse the sign (if the magnitude is correct)?

Comment: @Dai DOB is in the varchar format, So varchar convert to the date format

Comment: @Asokan Storing dates as strings is _wrong_. Why aren't you storing dates in a `date` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PensionerDOB, '-', 2), '-19', SUBSTRING_INDEX(PensionerDOB, '-', -1)), '%d-%M-%Y'), CURRENT_DATE) AS age
FROM pensionerbasicdata
```

The problem with 2-digit year fixed - **all** years are treated as `19xx`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f356258c99b20d13b0c4e2349b801f18

Comment: Fixed? By treating all twenty year olds as hundred and twenty year olds? It is `TIMESTAMPDIFF(year,` by the way, i.e. no quotes around year.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Pensioner of 20 years old? well, the fact that **all** years are treated as 20th centure year is marked as bold, if this is not safe then according CASE (instead of single `'-19'`) must be used. The problem with quoted unit name fixed, thanks.

Comment: SELECT `PensionerDOB`, YEAR(CURDATE()) as Year,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(PensionerDOB, '-', 2), '-19', SUBSTRING_INDEX(PensionerDOB, '-', -1)), '%d-%M-%Y'), CURRENT_DATE) AS age
FROM pensionerbasicdata

Comment: @Asokan Asterisk means that you may/must place needed column names and/or expressions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work,

Query,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(),YourDateofBirth)), '%Y')+0 AS Age from AgeCalculationFromDatetime
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `+0` part?

Comment: if we want to add same days in the age

Answer (score 0):

here Mysql is not parsing two-digit years as expected.. Instead of 1945- it's returning 2065,1953- it's returning 2053.
Please follow this link to parse the date with two digits years.
[how-to-use-str-to-date-mysql-to-parse-two-digit-year-correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45474147/how-to-use-str-to-date-mysql-to-parse-two-digit-year-correctly)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).